# Javascript code error

Tags: javascript

Hello Can Any one have idea about below code and its related error.

**code:**

```
Text = " <a href=""#"" onclick=""javascript:popup('" & dvStressdays.ClientID & "');" & _
                                               hdnCurrentSequenceName.ClientID & ".value='" & sequenceNode.Value & _
                                               hdnCurrentSequenceTestTypeId.ClientID & ".value='" & intSequencesTestTypesId & _
                                               "'; "">Change Stressdays</a>"
```

**Error**

Expected ';'

Info is appriciated!

Comment: you might want to review the code. It's totally wrecked.

Comment: for one thing, get rid of the starting `javascript:`. That's not necessary within an `onclick`.

Comment: post the code as it is received on the browser, not the server-side source

Comment: @DaveNewton I suspect that's the server side language using that, not his JS.

Comment: @David the `javascript:` is not required, but it would not break anything.

Comment: You have some `"foo.value='"` value, but no closing `'` on the first one, and no semicolon between them.

Comment: @All, FYI, this code is working great in existing applicaiton, am trying to add another hidden variable to existing code. that is hdnCurrentSequenceName.ClientID & ".value='" & sequenceNode.Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `javascript:`, but that doesn't break anything. The real error is, as the browser said, you are missing a semicolon (and a closing quote). I added it back (end of second line).

```
Text = " <a href=""#"" onclick=""popup('" & dvStressdays.ClientID & "');" & _
       hdnCurrentSequenceName.ClientID & ".value='" & sequenceNode.Value & "';" & _
       hdnCurrentSequenceTestTypeId.ClientID & ".value='" & intSequencesTestTypesId & _
       "'; "">Change Stressdays</a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing semicolon after you set the value for hdnCurrentSequenceName.ClientID.

```
...
hdnCurrentSequenceName.ClientID & ".value='" & sequenceNode.Value & "';" & _
...
```

Comment: Good to hear. Please accept the answer by clicking the green checkbox to the left of it :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputations.

Answer (score 0):

(the following assumes a .NET framework or something with similar functionality)

- you should be using a string builder, not string concatenation.
- you should be using string.format to place variable values in your strings.
- your javascript output is malformed
- anchor tags do not have a `value` attribute.

  ```
  Text = String.Format("<a href=""#"" onclick=""javascript:popup('{0}');"">Change Stressdays</a>", dvStressdays.ClientID)
  ```

Comment: Why would you use a StringBuilder? There's hardly any text here.

Comment: his example is concatenating 11 strings together, i'd consider that more than enough to use a stringbuilder. granted, the compiler probably optimizes it into a stringbuilder anyways, but it's a good habit to be in.

Comment: @Jbabey, Thank you for your time on this post. I think your code might work, If I fallow your code, I have to change existing code also. In this case, It can't help me. Thanks Again!

Comment: @jbabey that's very much a microoptimization. I think a platform that can handle thousands of web page requests per second can handle concatenating 11 strings together. string.format makes sense for readability. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html